# Socket's PrintWriter doesn't send until closed

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have client code that looks like:

```
Socket s = new Socket(server.getHostName(), server.getPort());
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
p.println(message);
p.flush();
s.shutdownOutput();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String newLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while((newLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    response.append(newLine);
System.out.println(response.toString());
p.close();
br.close();
```

and server code that looks like:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String nextLine;
StringBuffer request = new StringBuffer();

System.out.println("Starting read....");
String nextline;
while((nextline = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(nextline);
    request.append(nextline);
}
System.out.println("Message recived!!");
System.out.println("Request: " + request);

PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
p.println("Hello, fileclient!");
System.out.println("Message sent!!");

p.close();
br.close();
```

Before I put the line `s.shutDownInput()` the server code would hang at `br.readLine().` The way I managed to fix that is to close the `PrintWriter` some how, either through `p.close()` or through the current way which doesn't 
shutdown the socket like closing the `PrintWriter` through `p.close()` does. After that, the interaction between client and server is perfect.

Why does the `PrintWriter` or the `BufferedReader` not send/receive until the `PrintWriter` is closed somehow?

Comment: Why do you expect it to?  Buffering is normal, and closing a stream forces it to flush its contents.

Comment: I guess he want to keep the socket open so he can send down more data.

Comment: Just as a note nowadays you should use **try-with-resources** to automatically and correctly close resources like `Socket`s. It looks like this: `try (Socket s = new Socket(...)) { your code }`. Java now automatically closes all resources defined in the `try (...)` part when reaching the end (the closing `}`). This can be done with everything that implements `AutoCloseable` which are many classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

Comment: @Zabuza Thank you, I provided code that was relavent to the question. In the actual program, i use the try-with-resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with `PrintWriter`. It is an application protocol error on your part.

- The server is looping reading lines until end of stream.
- The client is sending one line and then not closing the socket, so no end-of-stream got sent (until you added the shutdown).
- The server is then responding.
- The client is then reading.

So the client doesn't read anything until the server gets out of the loop, and the server doesn't get out of its loop because the client is reading not closing.

So make up your mind. Probably the server should only read one line.

Comment: You and the @John Bollinger are both correct. I didn't know that the br.readLine() read until end of stream. I thought it went until there was no more lines to be read. Thank you very much! For future people, read until br.readLine() equals null or if it received and single 'q'.

Comment: The behaviour of `readLine()` is documented. It doesn't read until end of stream, but your code does, by looping until it returns null, which it does at, err, end of stream.

Answer (score 1):

Both sides are behaving exactly as you told them to do.  In particular, you instruct the server specifically to read everything the client sends before dispatching any response:

```
    String nextline;
    while((nextline = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(nextline);
        request.append(nextline);
    }
```

It is important to understand that that will not stop reading until an error or end of *stream*, where end of stream on a socket corresponds to the other end having been closed and all data having been read.  In other words, your server waits for the end of the whole conversation, not the end of a single message, before dispatching a response.

Since that's apparently not what you want, you need to implement a different strategy at the server for determining when to process the data received so far and send a response.  If you can be confident that your messages will not contain internal newlines, then that might be as simple as the server performing only **one** `br.readLine()` before sending each response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You and EJP were very helpful. Like I said above, I thought that it waited until there was no more things to be read, not until end of stream. I solved this by listening for a single 'q' and then processing the request.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone arrives here six years later, the block below is what allowed me to keep the input & output streams open, and send the bytes to a protocol for parsing:

```
    // KOTLIN
    reader!!.available().let {avail ->
        if (avail > 0) {
            val buffer = ByteArray(avail)
            reader!!.readFully(buffer, 0, avail)
            protocol!!.readData(buffer)
        }
    }
```